# How to properly get the ID of the fragment the button is assigned to

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

```
btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if(isChecked){
            //instance of a list
             spotsProvider.spotsList?.find { spots.ID.equals(spots.ID)}?.likes = spots.likes + 1
            numLikes.text = spots.likes?.toString()

            //refreshFragment(btn.context)
        }
            Toast.makeText(btn.context, if(isChecked) spots.ID.toString() else "do something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        render(spots)
        }
```

It generates a couple of fragments from a list/Or card fragements which have a like button [How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJFnJ.png)
the above function should return the ID of the selected card/fragment and modify it's like counter below.

The like counter and the images and name are provided to it from a list which the function should modify using the ID parameter in the list, noted that the list is in another class

List:

```
var spotsList = mutableListOf (
        Spots(
            "Volcan Cerro Negro1",
            0,
            "https://www.visitcentroamerica.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/ver-centroamerica-nicaragua-volc%C3%A1n-cerro-negro-08.jpg",
            1
        ),
        Spots(
            "Volcan Cerro Negro2",
            0,
            "https://static.dw.com/image/56796908_403.jpg",
            2
        ),
        Spots(
            "Volcan Cerro Negro3",
            0,
            "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/amz/worldservice/live/assets/images/2015/12/02/151202170824_la_ltima_vez_que_el_momotombo_entr_en_actividad_eruptiva_fue_en_1905_624x351_ap_nocredit.jpg",
            3
        ),
        Spots(
            "DC",
            0,
            "https://cursokotlin.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/wonder_woman.jpg",
            4
        )
```

Tried to check if it was reading the ID correctly , seems stuck on the ID 1 and doesn't register other like buttons like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IWnt.png) , however hen using the toast function it seems to know to which ID the button belongs to.

Thx in Advanced :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but the Toast isn't checking anything to do with the button - whatever `spots` is (it's defined outside of this button's click listener), it's just printing the `ID` of that. If all your listeners refer to that variable, they're all gonna see the same thing, with the same ID

Also `find { spots.ID.equals(spots.ID) }` is using `spots` again and comparing it to itself, so that predicate always returns true and you get the first item in the list. Then you set its `likes` to `spots.likes + 1` instead of incrementing its own `likes` value.

You probably want to do this, assuming `spots` is a `Spot` you're trying to find in the list:

```
// 'it' is the default name for the variable being passed in,
// i.e. the item in the list you're currently checking - you're looking for a match
spotsProvider.spotsList?.find { it.ID.equals(spots.ID) }?.likes += 1
```

This might be enough to fix it, if each button is in its own thing (like a `ViewHolder`) with its own value for `spots`